Reduce padding of Shopify Featured Collection Grid Images on Gem Theme
Our Featured Collection on our home page of our website is really tiny and looks blurred.
Please help!
The website address is liviana.co.za
I have tried resizing images, upscaling them, etc. And nothing is working.
I then realised, after inspecting the widget, that the grid items have a padding of 37px. There's no way to automatically remove this. I then tried to use Custom CSS, to no avail:
img-element { padding: 0px; }
I have also tried going through the theme code to source the code to reduce padding but could not find it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
